# How to create a container that fills up entire screen with no padding in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following div:

```
<div style="background:red;width:100%;height:100%">Red</div>
```

When I stick it into the page without a container div, I can see it. But when I stick it into a container

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="background:red;width:100%;height:100%">Red</div>
</div>
```

I can't see that div at all. When I stick it into an additional:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3">
        <div style="background:red;width:100%;height:100%">Red</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can see it, but there is a lot of padding and tons of spacing all around. How can I create a container div that doesnt have any margins/padding etc. that is equal to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, if you are using Bootstrap grid system, some margins and padding are added to maintain spacing between columns and page boundaries. So direct answer to your question is: no, you  can't.

However, you can simply have a div that is not wrapped in div with .container class - then your div will not have any margins and paddings derived from grid system.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8">8-units column</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; background: red;">Your div to be expanded to full page's width</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    Another div within grid system
  </div>
</div>
```